# Kendo UI MVC Grid row selecting

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I need to execute a History push state to some Action on Grid click...

I looked the API, and I think the Events Change its the right place to do that...

So, thats the code i´d like to put in there

```
"window.History.pushState(null, null," + "'" + Url.Action("Edit", "MyController") + "/' + Id);"
```

I used that on a similar JS Grid and works fine, but I dont know how to do that with Kendo UI MVC Wrapper...
I intend to use that directly on Grid definition, so I dont have to create any JS method... Something like that :

```
.Events(events => events.Change(x => "window.History.pushState..."))
```

Is that possible? How get the ID and declare Url.Action there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs for the "change" event](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-change) have an example of how to get the data item for the selected row(s).

The MVC helper expects the string name of a JS function to be passed to `events.Change()` but I think you can define a function there too.

So something like:

```
@{
    var url = Url.Action("Edit", "MyController");
}

...

.Events(events => events.Change(x => @"function (changeEvent) {
    var selectedRows = this.select();
    var dataItem;
    var numSelectedRows = selectedRows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numSelectedRows ; i++) {
        dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
        selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
        window.History.pushState(null, null, """ + url + @"/"" + dataItem.Id);
    }
}"))
```

I don't have a Kendo MVC project open in front of me to verify the syntax, but that should be pretty close, or at least get you pointed in the right direction.